# Does a data type exist in any language that spans a parameter range 0-1?

Tags: math, types, precision

I am often programming mathematical algorithms that assume a nondimensional parameter spans the continuous space from 0..1 inclusive. These algorithms could in theory benefit from maximum resolution over the parameter space and I've considered that it would be of use to expend the full 32 or 64 bits of precision over the parameter space, with none wasted for exponents or signs.

I imagine the methods would look similar to an unsigned integer divided by its maximum representable value. Does this exist already and if so where, if not, is there a compelling reason why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you simply do all calculations in integers from 0 to MAX_INT, keeping all the same formulas/algorithms/whatever and then use "unsigned integer divided by its maximum representable value" conversion as very final step before printing result to user (or otherwise outputting it - for example in intermediate logs)?

Comment: I suppose the same could be said for math algorithms generally, but the advent of floating point types simplified a lot of scientific computing challenges. Decimal data types resolved issues in financial computing specifically. I guess the question is one of whether there would be any benefit to introducing this 'nondimensional' data type to best capture all those algorithms that could make use of it. One potential application could be in graphics where all point coordinates in the scene extents are scaled to the 0-1 range.

Comment: It simply that most logical implementation of such type would have exactly this logic in it: getter/setter that converts 0..MAX_VALUE range to 0..1 and internally overloaded mathematical operators that simply do integer math.

Comment: Though if the property getter/setter consumes and returns traditional floating point values that might make the extra precision redundant.

Comment: Traditional float will lose precision on every calculation. Proper object with overloaded operations only will only "lose" on implicit conversion when, for example, it is being printed to screen, overloaded operations will operate with internal representation without "unwrapping" and "packing" it back every time. But even then you can make specialized setter/getter with arbitrary precision to eliminate even this problem.

Comment: I guess what I am hearing is that a new data type would have almost no benefit over custom implementations where necessary.

Comment: Yep, something like this: it is trivial enough and yet rarely need for someone to implement in some standard way.

Answer (score 0):

The representation doesn't make sense without algorithms. E.g. you could represent it as fixed point (i.e. 0..MAX_INT / MAX_INT) or floated point a mantissa and exponent (e.g. to have an ability to store a values like 1e-1000) or something custom (e.g. to have an ability to represent a number `1/π` precisely). After it you have define algos to manipulate the numbers in such representations. So, in other words there is no silver bullet to cover all cases. Only you know your task and could choose the best solution.

Moreover, the `continuous space` is impossible to represent using computes, because the space has infinite number of elements, so it cannot be algorithmized.